# Run Perl file with integer arguments from a Python script

Tags: python

I am trying to run the Perl script rtpc.pl from a Python script from the command line with two input arguments. Normally, I run the Perl script from the command line with two arguments:

```
perl rtpc.pl [ARG1] [ARG2]
```

What I want is a separate python script that I can call from the command line that I can input [ARG1] and [ARG2] into while compiling the Perl script rtpc.pl.

Something like:

```
python3 pyscript.py
```

So far, in my python script, I am using the subprocess module, but I am a little unsure how to pass arguments for my perl script.

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "rtpc.pl"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How would I input the arguments needed to equivalently run the Perl script terminal command? I should also mention that the shell that I am using is tcsh.

Comment: In python 3.5+ you want [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).  The `Popen` is an "_underlying interface_" recommended for "_more advanced_" needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them to the list you pass to `subprocess.Popen()`.

```
arg1 = 'foo'
arg2 = 'bar'
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "rtpc.pl", arg1, arg2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Do the arguments have to be encased in quotes? And can I pass integers?

Comment: You're starting a subprocess. That's done by passing a finite number of strings to a program. That's nothing specific to Python; that's how processes work at a fundamental level.

Comment: @Austin The arguments are all strings. You can convert integers with `str(variable)`.